# On functoriality of the Leray spectral sequence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

The Leray spectral sequence is functorial in the following sense: given a commutative square of spaces,
$$\begin{matrix} A & \to & B \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ C & \to & D  \end{matrix}$$
there is a map of spectral sequences from the Leray spectral sequence for $B \to D$ to the Leray spectral sequence for $A \to C$, which is compatible with the pullback map $H^\bullet(B) \to H^\bullet(A)$. More precisely, the map $H^\bullet(B) \to H^\bullet(A)$ is compatible with the Leray filtrations on both sides, and the induced morphism of associated gradeds is induced by the map between the spectral sequences.

However, the map $H^\bullet(B) \to H^\bullet(A)$ will in general not be *strictly* compatible with the Leray filtration, so the map on associated graded can in general look quite different from $H^\bullet(B) \to H^\bullet(A)$ itself. For instance, suppose that $A=B=C$, that $A\to B$ and $A \to C$ are the identity. Then $H^\bullet(B) \to H^\bullet(A)$ is the identity map, but the induced map of spectral sequences is one of the edge maps in the Leray spectral sequence for $B \to D$.

What conditions can I put on the square to ensure strict compatibility with the Leray filtration? Is cartesian enough? Are there more general hypotheses?

---

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are filtered modules. Then $f : M \to N $ is strictly compatible with the filtrations if $ f (M) \cap F_p N = f (F_pM) $ for all $p$.

Comment: What do you mean by "strictly compatible"?  That the filtration drop never occurs?

Comment: Being cartesian is not enough: an example is given by pulling back the Hopf fibration $p:S^3 \to S^2$ along itself.

Comment: I've added the definition.  Thanks for the example, Oscar!